# plone: read-only filesystem - can't edit contents

Tags: filesystems, plone, suse

due to a recent lack of space on the virtual machine (solved already) where I run Plone, the file system got locked by the OS (Suse Linux Enterprise) to read only mode. Since then I can't edit any content in Plone.

I found several links in the web that describe that problem, but none showed me how to solve it. I am currently not sure, if some Plone-user rights or something else changed. Where would be a good point to start debugging?

Christian

Comment: Did you restart Plone after the file system problem was cured? (I can't think of anything in Plone that would do this without intentional change.)

Comment: Hi Steve, yes. Finally there was a simple restart missing! :) Thanks for the hint!